# How do i get a random image from a folder python

Tags: python, discord.py

Ok so i have a folder with like 100+ memes for my discord bot, i don’t want to do this

```
Img = [“1.png”, “2.png”]
random.choice(Img)
```

NOTHING WRONG WITH EXAMPLE CODE

My code is not exactly like that but i don’t want to do that for every meme and more to be added

I’m using it for a discord bot, I’m just trying to get one random image to send with my bot

Comment: It's really not clear what you want, or what is wrong with your example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off @Sandsten's answer, here's what you can do to select `jpeg` and `png`:

```
import glob, random
file_path_type = ["./Memes/*.png", "./Memes/*.jpeg"]
images = glob.glob(random.choice(file_path_type))
random_image = random.choice(images)
```

It will randomly select the file type from `Memes` directory, then select based that selected file type. It should be equally as random. Just make sure to add other file types to `file_type` if you wish to add more types.

Comment: Could u edit is so i could have all the images in a folder and this code outside the folder 

RandImg.py(text)
Memes(folder)

Comment: @The_SCP_Master Try that. Let me know if it works

Comment: @The_SCP_Master Ah I see. Let me look into this once I'm home from work. It shouldn't be too hard of a fix, just can't test it here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’ll tell you if i solve it before you get home

Comment: I solved it, i was just testing it and didn’t put a jpeg photo in only png, thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should do return a random image name to be used

```
import os
import random

imgExtension = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg"] #Image Extensions to be chosen from
allImages = list()



def chooseRandomImage(directory="."):
    for img in os.listdir(directory): #Lists all files
        ext = img.split(".")[len(img.split(".")) - 1]
        if (ext in imgExtension):
            allImages.append(img)
    choice = random.randint(0, len(allImages) - 1)
    chosenImage = allImages[choice] #Do Whatever you want with the image file
    return chosenImage


randomImage = chooseRandomImage()
print(randomImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, you will get an array with all the image files ending with .png

```py
import glob, random
images = glob.glob("*.png"))
random_image = random.choice(images)
```